# Importing named exports from React does not work on Flow-type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flowtype, flow-typed

**Versions**

```
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"flow-bin": "0.107.0"
```

**The Problem**

I'm working on an on-going project, the team-lead and I agreed to enforce adding static typing using Flow because it is already setup, but they are not using it.

Whenever I import named exports from `React` it is complaining that there is no exported module with that name. (See the attached image).

I even tried creating a new RN project with the same version as the actual project but it still showing the same errors.

[image]

Comment: Please keep the questions professional and not opinioned.

Answer (score 2):

In `flow` there is no such type `React.FC` as it is Typescript type.

See all [Type References](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/) in related docs.

```
// TS
const Foo: React.FC<Props> = (props) => { ... }

// Flow
const Foo = (props: Props): React.Node => { ... }
```

Your code is referring to a typescript type in **javascript file with flow client**, don't be confused.

`React.FC` type comes from `@types/react/index.d.ts` as mentioned.

```
type FC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;
```

Comment: I'd also add that flow and the react team encourages using `import * as React from 'react';` when working with flow